# Celery tasks not being completely removed from queue

Tags: django, python-3.x, celery

I have a celery task that calls itself (with `do_stuff.apply_async(queue="foo")`). Previously I have ran `app.control.add_consumer("foo", reply=True)` so my workers can consume from this queue.

After some amount of time, I want to stop all the tasks from that queue and all running tasks that were launched from `do_stuff`.

So I run this code:

```
app.control.cancel_consumer("foo", reply=True)

i = app.control.inspect()
for queue in [i.active, i.scheduled, i.reserved]:
    for worker_name, worker_tasks in queue().items():
        for task in worker_tasks:
            args = ast.literal_eval(task["args"])
            if "do_stuff" in task["name"] and args[0] == crawler.name:
                app.control.revoke(task["id"], terminate=True)
```

This "works" kind of. It does stop all the running tasks from `do_stuff` and it does clear the scheduled tasks (or at least I can't see any in Flower, after running this code).

The problem is that if I run `app.control.add_consumer("foo", reply=True)` again, without running anything else, new tasks start running. That means that celery/redis, somehow, manages to keep tasks somewhere.

Why is that happening? Where are those "hidden" tasks saved? And how can I remove them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering to my own question: this happens because while I'm making the workers not to consume from the queue (by calling `cancel_consumer`), the queue itself still contains everything.

I have found a way to (programatically) flush the queue:

```
from celery.bin.celery import CeleryCommand
cmd = CeleryCommand()
super(CeleryCommand, cmd).execute_from_commandline([
    '',
    'purge',
    '-f',
    '-Q', queue_name,
    '-A', 'main'
])
```